# should I disable back up data when using flutter secure storage

Tags: flutter

Okay I am using flutter_secure_storage package in my project in the documentation it says

```
Note By default Android backups data on Google Drive. It can cause exception 
java.security.InvalidKeyException:Failed to unwrap key. You need to

disable autobackup, details
exclude sharedprefs FlutterSecureStorage used by the plugin, details
```

but I didnt do this step and my app is working fine on a physical phone so I really dont understand the
exception it might cause.

**My question:**
should I add it and what does this exception mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is required to disable autobackup because on some devices like samsung the shared pref and Android keystore content faces issues i.e throws error when trying to recover data from backup.

You can get the error on samsung devices after reinstalling the app.

That's the reason it is recommended to disable autobackup. But if you need the autobackup then you can still keep autobackup enable by making shared pref content disable by going through this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup